# java - decrypt a file with base64

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, base64

In my project a textfile is chosen and become encrypted. The encrypted text is saved seperatly as well as the key. Now I try to create a program which is decrypting the file when the right keyfile is available. I think the decrypting program needs to look pretty like the encrypting program just in `DECRYPT_MODE`. When I read in the key I don't know how to do the next step at it to decrypt the textfile. Maybe anyone can help me how I use the key from .txt file and use it to decrypt the encoded file.

The encrypting program:

```
public class encrypt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {
        //Key is created and saved in File
        KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecretKey myDesKey = keygenerator.generateKey();
        String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(myDesKey.getEncoded());
        Path keypath = Paths.get("C:/xxx/key.txt");
        Path keyfile = Files.createFile(keypath);
        Files.write(keyfile, encodedKey.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE);

        Cipher desalgCipher;
        desalgCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        desalgCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);

        Path target = Paths.get("C:/xxx/encrypted.txt");
        Path file = Files.createFile(target);

        Path path = Paths.get("test.txt");               
        try(InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(path);      
        CipherInputStream cipherIS = new CipherInputStream(is, desalgCipher);   
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cipherIS));){  
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                Files.write(file, line.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
            }
        }          
    }
}
```

Decrypt: read in the key and decrypt it

```
    public class decrypt {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {

            try {
                File fileDir = new File("C:/Users/JT/Desktop/key.txt");

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF-8"));

                String str;

                while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
                        in.close();
                } 
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

               byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(sb.toString());
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES"); 
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(sb.toString().getBytes(), "Base64");

    Cipher desalgCipher;
    desalgCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    desalgCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    Path path = Paths.get("encrypted.txt");                // path to your file
    try(InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(path);        // get an IS on your file
    CipherInputStream cipherIS = new CipherInputStream(is, desalgCipher);   // wraps stream using cipher
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cipherIS));){   // init reader.
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);

            }
        }

     }
}
```

Comment: You should actually attempt to write the decryption code first.  Unless you copy and pasted the encryption code.  In which case, this is a code request and is off-topic.  Don't copy and paste security critical code.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advise, but it doesn't help me on how I handle the key?

Comment: Uhhh... Yeah, I know.  You haven't included your attempt at writing the decryption code yet?

Comment: I edited the decryption part. The key is read in and the file is selected which shall be decrypted. But for soe reasons I get an error of `Wrong algorithm: AES or Rinjndael required`.  Do you know how to avoid it?

Comment: You know that base64 isn't an encryption algorithm right?  You can't create a base64 "key" because there is no such thing.

Comment: But I create an AES key and encode it with base64, or is that wrong?

Comment: You need to decode the base64 encoded key to a `byte[]` and then pass that as the key.  You would really benefit from actually **learning and understanding** what the code is doing, compared to just copying and pasting and hoping it works.

Comment: Well but decoding the key happens in a `byte[]`?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: I'm asking why the textfile is not being encoded while the key can be printed correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Your application is not being programmed the right way. Currently you try to encrypt by wrapping the input stream with a `CipherInputStream` instance. Then this instance again is wrapped with a `BufferedReader` instance.

So what you are doing is to first convert the bytes of the input file - probably text - into ciphertext. This ciphertext can contain *any byte value*. Then you try to read *those* bytes in line-by-line using the default character set and line endings. Obviously after encryption even the *notion* of lines doesn't exist anymore, so you'll loose data in that final step.

Then you convert back to bytes, which you then (somehow) try to decrypt. This will obviously fail as you lost data during the `readLine` statement.

---

What you should do is to read in the file using bytes. You can then write to a `CipherOutputStream`. If the file with the ciphertext needs to be actual text you can use a `Base64` stream which the new `java.util.Base64` nicely provides.

Only once you programmed the encryption correctly you can try and reverse the process. As long as data is lost obviously the decryption will fail (with an error or garbage output, depending on the mode and your luck).

---

If you're unlucky you will end up with code that works 99% of the time. So good luck and heed the comments: don't try and perform encryption without understanding what you're doing. It *will* end with tears - or a smashed keyboard.